# Clicking on google results appends the url many times

Tags: javascript

When i click on the link GoogleResults - for each click it appends the url, i want to append url only on the first click. Please help how to resolve this issue

```
  <a href="mailto:googlehelp_r@gmail.com?Subject=Help%20Google-%20Results&body="                    onclick="this.href+=escape(window.location.href)">GoogleResults</a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload=function(){
    var lnkMail=document.getElementById("mail");
    lnkMail.setAttribute("href", lnkMail.href + escape(window.location.href) );
}
</script>

<a id="lnkMail" href="mailto:googlehelp_r@gmail.com?Subject=Help%20Google-%20Results&body=">GoogleResults</a>
```

It is a bad practice to change the href attribute directly on the click event, and it is another one to add inline scripts in the markup. Ideally, you want the user to know what's going on before he clicks on a link. Then, if he chooses to disable JS, it is better for him to have disabled features than errors from his browser.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: page url not at all getting appended with above change

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
function getUrl() {
    return this.href+=escape(window.location.href);
}
<a href="mailto:googlehelp_r@gmail.com?Subject=Help%20Google-%20Results&body=" onclick="return getUrl(this.href);">GoogleResults</a>
```

for demonstration plz